# Any scanner apps for Android?

Tags: android, printing, scanning

I'd like to have an app that can use a real network printer-scanner to scan documents on Android, but all I can find are apps which use the camera.

Are there apps that could use a printer to scan documents?

Thanks!

Comment: Some printers have this feature. Check into Brother and HP printers. They can scan directly to mobile if on the same network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to have TWAIN scanner, visible in your local network, WiFi connection in your local network and application like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mopria.scan.application)

Depend of WiFi settings you may need to have your scanner connected to WiFi, not wired lan.

Comment: This seems to do what I want so I'm taking this as a solution, thanks! Are there open source apps for this though?

Comment: @TheDevKiller, from what I found they involve PC as service to manage the scans. Is this OK for you?

Comment: It's a bit constraining. But anyway I found Lexmark's app which does this great so it will do the job. Thanks again!